# Cannot click ListViewCell with null value

Tags: ui-automation, white-framework

The tests I am developing access the DataGrid cells the following way:

```
 window.Get<ListView>(gridName).Rows.First().Cells.First()
```

Then clicking a cell with `UIItem.Click()` method works fine, **unless the cell is bound to a null value**. In such a case, I get an exception:

```
Failed to click on ListViewCell. AutomationId:, Name:, ControlType:text, FrameworkId:WPF, bounds empty
```

Which makes sense, as apparently, an AutomationElement related to that cell is a  TextBlock of 0 boundaries.
Is there some possible workaround to click such a cell so the tests work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What seems to be a good enough workaround is the following:

```
this.window.Mouse.Location = Point.Subtract(cellToClick.ClickablePoint, new Vector(12, 6)); 
this.window.Mouse.Click(this.window.Mouse.Location);
```

So I just set the mouse location using property `TestStack.White.UIItems.Mouse` so it is situated right above the cell, then click.